# gradlew assembleRelease will attempt to release memory

Tags: react-native, gradle

[will attempt to release memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0Zxx.jpg)

[problem with the following location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PD1Mh.png)

[gradle.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GYeb.png)

./gradlew assembleRelease crashes windows on app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets, it enters an eternal loop spitting repeteaded messages on console until it dies and windows stops responding.

What should I do in first place? I have no idea what is causing this issue

package.json

```
      "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome": "^0.3.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.5",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^6.2.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.6.2",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "flow-bin": "^0.170.0",
    "i18next": "^21.8.9",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^6.1.4",
    "i18next-http-backend": "^1.4.1",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "npm": "^8.11.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-i18next": "^11.17.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.5.11",
    "react-native-image-modal": "^2.0.4",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^4.8.4",
    "react-native-mask-input": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.12.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.2.5",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.13.1",
    "react-native-send-intent": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.4.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-video": "^5.2.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.22.7",
    "react-native-youtube-iframe": "^2.2.2",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.67.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a file named `gradle.properties` under `android` folder and this to it. This increases JVM heap size.

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=4096m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

Comment: org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m -XX:+UseParallelGC,
MaxPermSize unrecognized parameter

Comment: @richardbruner Is the file placed correctly under `android` dir and make sure you paste the exact thing? If this doesn't work, then please use `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m` only

Comment: Added screenshots, I used assembleRelease without --debug and --info, I see a problem with react-native-video package

Comment: thank your patience, I reinstalled react-native-video it worked